# Hosted emails on cPanel - How can I stop a user form deleting emails?

Tags: email, email-filter, cpanel

Just wondering how can I stop a user from deleting emails on a mailbox that is being hosted on cPanel?

I have already created another mailbox that will auto-forward incoming emails - but I would like to keep a copy of the sent emails as well

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

cPanel does not have any native features that prevent users from deleting emails.
The [email archive feature](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/82Docs/Archive) is probably the closest you can get without modifying cPanel.